# Jquery moving to next row's input element by id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```js
  $('#Cart tbody tr #quantity').on('keydown', function (e) {

        var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

        if (keyCode == 9) {
            $(this).closest('tr').next().find('input[type=number]').focus();
        }

    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="Cart" style="border-color: transparent;" class="table table-hover table-striped well">
  <thead class="thead-inverse">
    <tr>
      <th class="col-lg-1 text-center">Quanity</th>
      <th class="col-lg-3 text-center">Comment</th>
   
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr id="7392036">
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" value="0">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputforcomment" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
      <tr id="7392036">
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" value="0">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputforcomment" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
      <tr id="7392036">
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" value="0">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputforcomment" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
      <tr id="7392036">
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" value="0">
      </td>
      <td class="text-center col-lg-3">
        <input type="text" maxlength="15" class="form-control" id="inputforcomment" value="">
      </td>
      <td class="col-lg-1 text-center">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>
        </button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I have a table with multiple rows and each row has two inputs. Both have different ids. I'm trying to focus on next row's input element by selecting the id when user presses tab key . Here's my code:

```
  $('#Cart tbody tr #quantity').on('keydown', function (e) {

    var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if (keyCode == 9) {
        $(this).closest('tr').next().find('#quantity').focus();
    }

});
```

While doing this, it selects the wrong textbox on the next row.Any help would be appreciated. thanks

Comment: Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt e.g. as a [Stack Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/), so we can try to solve your problem and explain why your own attempt failed - that way you can learn something useful for your future development, as well as getting an answer to this single problem.

Comment: Are there multiple elements with same `id` in `html`?

Comment: HTML requires tag ids to be unique.

Comment: @Andreas I have edited the post

Comment: Why not simply use the HTML `tabindex` parameter on your inputs to control the tab order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No jQuery required. Just use the `tabindex` attribute and hook into the browser's native behaviour for applying `focus` state on tab key presses.

Example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" tabindex="1">
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" tabindex="2">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Recommended for accessibility too](http://webaim.org/techniques/keyboard/tabindex).